# profile information doesn't display current user log in

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

```
  TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  Profile? profileModel;

  User? user

  Future getUserData() async {
    User userData = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    var userID = userData.uid;
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    var docSnapshot = await collection.doc(userID).get();

    Map<String, dynamic> data = docSnapshot.data()!;
    setState(() {
      email.text = data['email'];
      username.text = data['username'];
      phone.text = data['phone'];
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getUserData();
  }

      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: username,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black87,
                      ),
                      labelText: "Username",
                      hintText: '${username.text}',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.perm_identity_outlined,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                      ),
                  ),

                  SizedBox(height: 27),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.black87,
                      minimumSize: const Size(500, 50),
                    ),
                    child: Text("Update"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
    );
  }
```

I don't know if i doing wrong but my user current login doesn't display the data in the textField when user login their profile. I did create profile model to retrieve the data from firebase. Please someone me how to figure it out. I already fetch the data from currentUser from firebase

Comment: are you recieving datas? have you printed it to know to recieving  data or not?

Answer (score 0):

the problem with this is your getUserData() function is an asynchronous function so its value needs to be awaited but the init state won't allow that neither will it let you setState so to solve this use postFramecallback like this

```
 @override
    void initState() {
      // TODO: implement initState
      super.initState();
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async { 
       await getUserData(); 
},);}
```